# Return the original message sent to Hubot

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

Is there a way to return the original message that Hubot hears/responds to?

Tried to access `message` and `@message` but that just seemed to error out when called.

Looking for something like:

```
robot.respond /test/, (msg) ->
  msg.send msg.the_message_that_the_user_typed_in
```

In this example it would echo back the entirety of the text that the user typed in.

In actuality I'll be playing with the text and stripping some things out, but I want an exact copy of the original text for messing around with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using catchAll:

```
robot.catchAll (msg) ->
  msg.send msg.message.text
```

However it will match a message that no other matchers matched. If you want to catch absolutely everything, you'll have to do this:

```
robot.respond /(.*)/, (msg) ->
  msg.send msg.match[1]
```

Update:

Question was how to get the original message, not how to catch all messages. Answer:

```
robot.respond /test/, (msg) ->
  msg.send msg.message.text
```

Comment: I don't want to match everything said in the chat room, or everything said to hubot, just want to be able to use the original text that hubot is responding to.

Comment: I suppose you could do something like this, and then do further checks afterwards?

Is that an expensive operation?

Comment: If you don't call `msg.finish()`, other listeners will continue to handle your message.

And original text is simply `msg.message.text`.